# Get list of items where their ID is equal to some Values - linq c#

Tags: c#, linq

Here is a query:

```
from order in db.tblCustomerBuys
where selectedProducts.Contains(order.ProductID)
select order.CustomerID;
```

`selectedProducts` is a list containing some target products IDs, for example it is `{ 1, 2, 3}`. 
The query above will return customerIDs where they have bought one of the `selectedProducts`. for example if someone has bought product 1 or 2, its ID will be in result.

But I need to collect CustomerIDs where they have bought all of the products. for example if someone has bought product 1 AND 2 AND 3 then it will be in result.

How to edit this query?

the tblCustomerBuys are like this:

```
CustomerID - ID of Customer
ProductID - the product which the customer has bought
```

something like this:

```
CustomerID      ProdcutID
---------------------------
110              1
110              2
112              3
112              3
115              5
```

Updated:

due to answers I should do grouping, for some reason I should use this type of query:

```
var ID = from order in db.tblCustomerBuys
         group order by order.CustomerID into g
         where (selectedProducts.All(selProdID => g.Select(order => order.ProductID).Contains(selProdID)))
         select g.Key;
```

but it will give this error:
`Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.`

Comment: I think you need to add the structure of your database too. How are Order and Product in order connected?

Comment: how does the multiple purchase of a product look in one entry of `tblCustomerBuys` ? I see only one field `ProductID` up to now, which (I assume) will have only a single value. Or am I wrong

Comment: @MongZhu: this is the relation table between customers and (purchased) prodcuts. So repeating `CustomerID` means this customer has bought multiple prodcts.

Comment: @TimSchmelter ok now I understand it, thanx

Comment: *but it will give error* What error (message)? And could you finally specify the LINQ provider used, apparently it's not LINQ to Objects which supports every construct that compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The updated query is the general LINQ solution of the issue.

But since your query provider does not support mixing the in memory sequences with database tables inside the query (other than `Contains` which is translated to SQL `IN (value_list)`), you need an alternative equivalent approach of `All` method, which could be to count the (distinct) matches and compare to the selected items count.

If the `{ CustomerID, ProductID }` combination is unique in `tblCustomerBuys`, then the query could be as follows:

```
var selectedCount = selectedProducts.Distinct().Count();
var customerIDs =
    from order in db.tblCustomerBuys
    group order by order.CustomerID into customerOrders    
    where customerOrders.Where(order => selectedProducts.Contains(order.ProductID))
        .Count() == selectedCount
    select customerOrders.Key;
```

And if it's not unique, use the following criteria:

```
where customerOrders.Where(order => selectedProducts.Contains(order.ProductID))
    .Select(order => order.ProductID).Distinct().Count() == selectedCount
```

Comment: nice code, it works but I edited it a bit! your code has a small problem : change `selectedProducts.Contains(order => order.ProductID)` to `selectedProducts.Contains(order.ProductID)`, that's it ;)

Answer (score 3):

As your question is written, it is a bit difficult to understand your structure. If I have understood correctly, you have an enumerable `selectedProducts`, which contains several Ids. You also have an enumeration of `order` objects, which have two properties we care about, `ProductId`  and `CustomerId`, which are integers.

In this case, this should do the job:

```
ver result = db.tblCustomerBuys.GroupBy(order => order.CustomerId)
                               .Where(group => !selectedProducts.Except(group).Any())
                               .Select(group => group.Key);
```

What we are doing here is we are grouping all the customers together by their `CustomerId`, so that we can treat each customer as a single value. Then we are treating `group` as a superset of `selectedProducts`, and using a a piece of linq trickery commonly used to check if one enumeration is a subset of another.  We filter `db.tblCustomerBuys` based on that, and then select the `CustomerId` of each order that matches.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Any condition of Linq. 
Step 1 : Create list of int where all required product id is stored  
Step 2: Use Any condition of linq to compare from that list

```
List<int> selectedProducts = new List<int>() { 1,2 } // This list will contain required product ID

db.tblCustomerBuys.where(o=> selectedProducts .Any(p => p == o.ProductID)).select (o=>o.order.CustomerID); // This will return all customerid who bought productID 1 or 2
```

Comment: Thanks, But I need to return all customerid who bought productID 1 `AND` 2